# JSLink: Render after SP-functions were executed

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering, rendering

I want to execute a function getdata() which uses SP.ClientContext. This function gives me some data from different lists on a page. I want to use this data to render my page with jslink.

My Problem:

```
(function(){

    getdata()

    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.View = myfunction;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();
```

at this point SP.ClientContext is an undefined function.

when i go this way:

```
(function(){

  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getdata");

    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.View = test1;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);

})();
```

it loads the data but the data comes too late for the rendering.

Do you have an idea how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SP.SOD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410742%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Example:

```
(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
    getdata();

    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.View = myfunction;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
    });
})();
```